# Count is not returning correct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

```
table_orders - order_id, order_datetime
table_order_details - order_id, product_sell_price, quantity
```

I want to get total sell amount month wise with number of orders in that month. This is my query.

```
select SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) Total,
    count(O.order_id) Count, MONTH(order_datetime) Month,
    MONTHNAME(order_datetime) MonthName, YEAR(order_datetime) YEAR 
from 
table_orders O 
INNER JOIN 
table_order_details OD
    ON O.order_id = OD.order_id 
group by MONTH(order_datetime), YEAR(order_datetime)
order by order_datetime;
```

All values are correct except number of orders of that month. I think its giving the count of order_id after INNER JOIN of both tables.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Instead of count(O.order_id) Count use count(DISTINCT O.order_id) Count

Comment: What do you need if not the numer of orders after the tables are joined and grouped? Which columns are your keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`COUNT (DISTINCT column)`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php) which will make sure you are counting only unique order `ID`'s :

```
select SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) Total,
       count(DISTINCT O.order_id) Count,
       MONTH(order_datetime) Month,
       MONTHNAME(order_datetime) MonthName,
       YEAR(order_datetime) YEAR
from table_orders O
INNER JOIN table_order_details OD 
 ON O.order_id = OD.order_id
group by MONTH(order_datetime), YEAR(order_datetime)
order by order_datetime;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Its working as expected. :)

Comment: No problem mate :) @DeveshAgrawal